# Mongoose, filter by date string 'DDMMYY'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb that has the dates stored as a string in the 'DDMMYYY' format.  Is there an easy way to find all documents with a date that is older than a given date?  The only thing I can think of doing is adding a new field in the document and write a script that takes the date string then converts it to a date object and saves it to the new field but I would rather avoid doing that. :)

Comment: Time to get over putting that off. The core problem ( aside from storing as a string takes a lot more bytes than a BSON Date ) is that since your dates start with the "day" and not the "year", they are not "lexically ordered" even as a string. The only other alternative is to run a calculation over the whole collection every time you want to query. And that's not a real alternative.  If the collection was small enough for calculating to not be a problem, then converting should equally be no issue. Converting the dates is the only real solution.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks.  That's what I needed to hear although it's not what I wanted to hear.  :)